# Testing authorization on API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

- I'm using Symfony 4.4 and *api-platform/api-pack* v1.2.1
- I've created a custom voter that support string with prefix `PERM_`
- I set an endpoint (`/api/roles`) to have `security: 'is_granted("PERM_READ_USER")'`
- I create a test like below:

```
    /**
     * @depends testLoginRegularUser
     * @param $token
     * @return string JWT Token
     */
    public function testRegularUserReadRole($token)
    {
        $this->expectException(AccessDeniedHttpException::class);
        $this->expectExceptionCode(403);
        $response = static ::createClient()->request('GET', '/api/roles',[
            'json' => [
                'page' => 1
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ]
        ]);
        return $token;
    }
```

And I always get error message:

```
Testing App\Tests\Functional\GroupRoleTest
.2020-01-06T00:49:48+00:00 [error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: "Access Denied." at /home/vagrant/Code/wikaunting/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php line 137
FS                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 14.27 seconds, Memory: 44.50 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Functional\GroupRoleTest::testRegularUserReadRole
Failed asserting that exception of type "Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException" is thrown.
```

When I test using rest client (Insomenia), it return

```
{
  "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Access Denied.",
  "trace": [
  {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/security-http\/Firewall\/ExceptionListener.php",
      "line": 137,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall",
      "short_class": "ExceptionListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\ExceptionListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handleAccessDeniedException",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/security-http\/Firewall\/ExceptionListener.php",
      "line": 102,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall",
      "short_class": "ExceptionListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\ExceptionListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "onKernelException",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/Debug\/WrappedListener.php",
      "line": 126,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "WrappedListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "__invoke",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 264,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "doDispatch",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 239,
      "args": [
        [
          "array",
          [
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "callListeners",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 73,
      "args": [
        [
          "array",
          [
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/Debug\/TraceableEventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 168,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 207,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ExceptionEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.exception"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handleThrowable",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 79,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ],
        [
          "integer",
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Kernel.php",
      "line": 201,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ],
        [
          "integer",
          1
        ],
        [
          "boolean",
          true
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "Kernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/wikaunting\/public\/index.php",
      "line": 25,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought it might return *AccessDeniedException*, not *AccessDenied**Http**Exception* so I change the test to

```
$this->expectException(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException::class);
```

But it still return similar error

```
1) App\Tests\Functional\GroupRoleTest::testRegularUserReadRole
Failed asserting that exception of type "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException" is thrown.
```

**Question**

- Is it supposed to return an exception?
- The `[error] Uncaught PHP Exception ...` message always appear. How to make it dissappear?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing functional with unit testing.
`$this->expectException` is used for unit testing, when your code throws an exception.

In this case, you are doing a HTTP request with the client, which will return a response and won't throw an exception. You should check that the response status code is 403.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way to make PHPUnit to hide the exception message coming from the code? Because there will be a lot of exception message if I'm testing a lot of 403 test. Or is it better to just display it?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "hide the exception message".
You whole test should look something like this

`public function testRegularUserReadRole($token)
    {
        $response = static ::createClient()->request('GET', '/api/roles',[
            'json' => [
                'page' => 1
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ]
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(403, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
`

Comment: Exception message is always printed on terminal `[error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: "Access Denied."` every time there are `is_granted` check.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that that Exception is not thrown on your test. It is thrown "serverside" as your request is denied. Hence you should not assert an Exception is thrown but rather check the statuscode and the response of that request in your test. 
API Platform provides helper methods for this.

Checkout:

```
self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame
self::assertJsonContains
```